# Java GC - Is Minor GC Collection a STW event?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Does GC need to “Stop The World” for Minor GC or only for Full GC? As I understand, a minor GC will happen when there is no space available in EDEN to allocate an object, so does that mean that for each minor GC there will be a STW event?

Comment: Typically yes.  Which is one reason why Eden space should be relatively small.  (But your reasoning is not correct.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen, mind if I ask why is the reasoning not correct?

Comment: Yes, for each minor collection there will be a STW pause. What is a bit "worse", it can't be partial in case of G1, it must scan all the young regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading several books I found that a Minor GC is always a Stop The World event, which will stop all the application threads and will normally have a short duration, as opposed to a GC pause for Full GC, which will take considerably much more time because it will run on Both Young and Old generations. So both Minor GC and Full GC are always Stop the World events.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends".

With most modern Java collectors, a minor (young / Eden space) collection is indeed a stop-the-world collection.  This is not a direct logical consequence of minor GC's being triggered by a young space filling up.  (Other strategies are possible for triggering a minor GC, or for dealing with a young space filling up.)  Rather it is just ... they way that most Java GCs are implemented.

One exception is ZGC which is not generational.  Hence there is no such thing as a minor collection.  Instead, when the GC is triggered there is a short (less than 10ms) stop the world event while the GC roots are found.  A second exception is the Shenandoah GC, which is likewise not generational.

(And of course, the original Java 1.1 GC was a mark-sweep collector, non-generational and stop-the-world.)

Comment: I don't get where "it depends" is coming from. There is no generational collector at the moment where a minor collection would be concurrent. There is simply not. So it does not "depend", it is a "fact".

Comment: No.  It is not a fact.  It is a generalization from a small set of data-points.  The fact that there isn't currently a generational Java GC where minor collection isn't stop the world doesn't mean there couldn't be one.

Comment: I have to admit that this is a rather interesting view, does not mean I agree with, but still your point is interesting.